# Using .matches() on integer types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, arel

I have a Rails 4 application backed by Postgres and one of my tables looks like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20141117132948) do
  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"
  ...
  create_table "boards", force: true do |t|
    ...
    t.string "part_name", null: false
    t.string "details", limit: 1024
    t.integer "sku", limit: 8, null: false
    t.integer "ct_id", limit: 8, null: false, default: 0
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

And I want to be able to find all records that match a given search term. For example, if the search term is `123` then I want to be able to find all boards whose `part_name`,`details`,`sku` or `ct_id` contains `123`. For example, I would like a board with sku of '9371239583' to be matched since it contains the sequence '123' in it.

This is the code that I'm using to find records that match.

```
t = Board.arel_table
q = params[:q] # This is the search term, e.g. '123'

@boards = @boards.where(
  t[:part_name].matches("%#{q}%")
  .or(t[:details].matches("%#{q}%"))
  .or(t[:sku].matches("%#{q}%"))   # This doesn't work because 'sku' is an integer
  .or(t[:ct_id].matches("%#{q}%")) # same here
)
```

I know that the SQL statement `select * from boards where cast(sku as text) like '%123%'` works fine but I can't find a way to tie both things together.

Is there a way to solve this problem without making changes to the DB schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your problems is that the default index type in postgres is btree, and although it's pretty good at `LIKE 'blah%'`, it's not very good at `LIKE '%blah'` [1].  To fix this, you should use a gist or gin index with the `pg_trgm` extension [2].  To install this, you should need to run the following command **once** on your database:

```
create extension pg_trgm;
```

Another is that you're comparing multiple columns at once.  One way of handling this would be to index on an expression [3].  The disadvantage of this (and the solution I'll give you in general) is that it will slow down updates significantly.

```
CREATE INDEX board_concat_idx ON boards USING gin ((part_name || ' ' || details || ' ' || sku || ' ' || ct_id) gin_trgm_ops)
```

Finally, you should have the following performant indexed query:

```
SELECT * FROM boards WHERE (part_name || ' ' || details || ' ' || sku || ' ' || ct_id) LIKE '%123%'
```

Note - I have concatenated these columns with spaces, but you should be sure to do it with a character/sequence that will never show up in the columns or query.  This is important, because you don't want part_name to end in 1, and details to start with 23, and get a match.

PS. I'm hoping you're on at least postgres 9.1. Also, I'm pretty curious why you need this.

1. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/indexes-types.html
2. http://www.depesz.com/2011/02/19/waiting-for-9-1-faster-likeilike/
3. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/indexes-expressional.html

Comment: Thanks Ramfjord, this does exactly what I wanted.

Comment: As for "I'm pretty curious why you need this", the reason is that the SKU and CT fields are numbers that break down in groups like 123-4567-8910. The idea is to let people search for a given board by providing only part of the SKU or CT (e.g. passing "4567").